# Javascript - Call Two Functions at Onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

I have two functions; one that validates the form, the other executes some code if the first function returns `true`.

```
<form name="calculator" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm(); result(trueOrFalse);" onreset="clearForm()">
```

The `checkForm()` function is defined as follows:

```
function checkForm() {
    var valid = true;
    var radios1 = document.getElementsByName("item");
    var radios2 = document.getElementsByName("postage");

    if (document.getElementById("constituency").value == 0) {
        document.getElementById("constituency").style.border = "1px solid #a60f28";
        document.getElementById("constituency").style.borderRadius = "2.5px";
        document.getElementById("conWarning").style.display = "block";
        valid = false;
    }

    //similar code as above for other fields

    trueOrFalse = valid;
    return valid;
}
```

The `result(valid)` function is defined as:

```
function result(valid) { //use trueOrFalse as parameter
    if (valid == true) {
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Yay"; //test display value
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "0";
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "inline";
    }

    return valid;
}
```

The goal here is to check first if the form filled out by the user is valid; if it is then produce a value to show to the user in the HTML as follows:

```
<div id="pound">&#163; <div id="result">0</div></div>
```

I'm not sure if the way I'm calling my two functions is correct/legal or if it is, whether the value to be display by the `result(valid)` function has been written correctly. The form is supposed to act as a calculator.

Comment: why not call `result()` from `checkForm()` function

Comment: `onsubmit="return result( checkForm() )"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
trueOrFalse = valid;
return valid;
```

Try this:

```
return result(valid);
```

Then remove `result(trueOrFalse);` from your `onsubmit`.

Comment: Thank you, it enabled me to write up some code to also stop the form from reloading on submit :)